# Use different javascript files for each page on website

Tags: php, theme-development, themes, javascript

I'm currently trying to create my first ever theme on wordpress. I'm hosting it locally until I can get it all working and then I will use the theme on a website.

Everything was going great until I got to the javascript. Each page on the theme has a character counter box which counts up counters as the user enters them. Each of these boxes has it's own javascript file.

I put one javascript file in the header.php file and that page that uses that file works (the home page), but I want to be able to create different page templates and on those templates use different files?

Is this possible.

(Not sure if I've explained this well enough, as I said I'm new to the whole theme development side of wordpress)

Thanks in advance, and be sure to ask for more details.

```
    <?php

function themeslug_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', '/js/char-counter.min.js', false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_script' );

// Register Custom Navigation Walker
require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');

// Theme Support
function wpb_theme_setup(){
    // Nav Menu
    register_nav_menus(array(
      'primary' => __('Primary Menu ')
    ));
}

  add_action('after_setup_theme', 'wpb_theme_setup');

  // Register scripts/styles. They can be optionally enqueued later on.
  add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wpse248829_register_scripts' );
  function wpse248829_register_scripts() {
      wp_register_script( 'character-counter-script-js', get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/themes/char-counter/js/char-counter.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), true );
      wp_register_script( 'tweet-counter', get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/themes/char-counter/js/tweet-counter.min.js', array(), true );
      wp_register_script( 'title-tag-counter-script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/themes/char-counter/js/title-tag.min.js', array(), true );
      wp_register_script( 'description-counter-script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/themes/char-counter/js/description-tag.min.js', array(), true );
  }

  // Enqueue scripts/styles.
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse248829_enqueue_scripts' );
  function wpse248829_enqueue_scripts() {
      // Load everywhere.
      wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
      wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);

      // Only enqueue scripts/styles on static front page.
      if ( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'character-counter-script-js' );
    }

      if ( is_page_template( 'tweet-template.php' ) ) {
          wp_enqueue_script( 'tweet-counter' );
      }

      if ( is_page_template( 'title-tag-template.php' ) ) {
          wp_enqueue_script( 'title-tag-counter-script' );
      }

      if ( is_page_template( 'description-tag-template.php' ) ) {
          wp_enqueue_script( 'description-counter-script' );
      }
  }
```

That's what my functions.php file looks like

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-GB" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">

<head>

  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
  <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Theme CSS -->


    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico">

    <script src="//load.sumome.com/" data-sumo-site-id="63887403fa39b3ec361069237f61eca50baf36e10e2973ac54b998b5095b3bb2" async="async"></script>


    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

        <title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>

        <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>

<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">

    <div id="wrapper" class="clearfix" itemprop="mainContentOfPage">

    <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'm1_logo' ) ) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" id="site-logo" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">

                    <img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'm1_logo' ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>">

                    </a>

                  <?php else : ?>

                    <hgroup>
                        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                        <p class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></p>
                    </hgroup>

                <?php endif; ?>
          </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'menu'              => 'primary',
                    'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                    'depth'             => 2,
                    'container'         => 'div',
                    'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                    'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                    'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                    'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                );
            ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

That's my header.php file

Comment: Why does each counter box have its own javascript file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I put one javascript file in the header.php file and that page that
>   uses that file works (the home page)

Don't do that. Use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) instead.

You can use [conditional tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) to load scripts and styles in the desired locations. For example, to check if a particular page template is being used, you'd use `is_page_template()`.

Scripts and styles can be registered on the `wp_loaded` hook, then enqueued on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook:

```
// Register scripts/styles. They can be optionally enqueued later on.
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wpse248829_register_scripts' );
function wpse248829_register_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'character-counter-script-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/char-counter.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    wp_register_script( 'tweet-counter', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/tweet-counter.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    wp_register_script( 'title-tag-counter-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/char-counter/js/title-tag.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    wp_register_script( 'description-counter-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/description-tag.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
}

// Enqueue scripts/styles.
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse248829_enqueue_scripts' );
function wpse248829_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Load everywhere.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    // Probably not needed, because it was already specified as a dependency.
    // wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

    // Only enqueue scripts/styles on static front page.
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'character-counter-script-js' );
    }

    if ( is_page_template( 'tweet-template.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'tweet-counter' );
    }

    if ( is_page_template( 'title-tag-template.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'title-tag-counter-script' );
    }

    if ( is_page_template( 'description-tag-template.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'description-counter-script' );
    }
}
```

Comment: would I do this on the functions.php file?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Nothing seems to be happening for me

Comment: Okay, please update your question with the calls to `wp_enqueue_script()` that you are using, as well as the names of your template files. The answer I've posted uses made up examples, and maybe something is being lost in translation here. Also, see the edit I made to the answer; don't place JS/styles directly in the header.

Comment: I've updated my answer with code from your updated question. The main issue I saw was that you were doing this `get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/themes/char-counter/js/char-counter.min.js'` Take a look at the docs for [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/), particularly the user-contributed examples. The function already gets the URI to the theme's directory so your code had some redundancy which broke the path. If something isn't working, be sure and check the browser's error console.

Comment: thanks for your help, do you mind helping me fix another issue. I've installed yoast and added a description to my homepage, but for some reason it isn't showing in the page source. Here is my current description tag `<meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" />`

Comment: You got it, Tim! Did we solve it? If so, please click the check mark to close this question out. If not, let me know -- we'll get it! As for the Yoast stuff, third-party plugins are off-topic here on WPSE, but to throw you a bone, I think you want to leave that meta tag out of your header. Make sure your `header.php` is calling `wp_head();` and Yoast should then do all the heavy lifting for your meta description tags for the various pages in your site.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Hate to be annoying but can I ask you another question. I've used the bootstrap navwalker menu on the website and I've installed it, but it doesn't work on mobile. The hamburger menu doesn't show any of the pages. I've inculded my header.php code and my function file is already there.

Comment: Happy to help, Tim, but please post a new question for the Bootstrap issue (only one question per post on WPSE or any Stack Exchange site for that matter). It might be better to post this on Stack Overflow since this site is dedicated to WordPress core functionality but feel free to try here. Make sure to include all of your script/style enqueue stuff in the post and I'm sure someone will chime in.